# How to fix the error "ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range" when linking an object built from assembler source on XCode / Mac?

Tags: c++, linker, embedded, clang

I'm making a C++ app for multiple platforms, and I have a large byte array that I'd like to embed in the app (it's around 40MB).

Previously I was generating a C++ header file containing the data represented as a C++ array, but it takes a very long time to compile. I'm now trying to generate an assembler source file, use the "incbin" directive to include the data, and then link the resultant object file into my app, thus removing the need to involve the C++ compiler.

The platform I'm having trouble with is Mac. I'm compiling using XCode 13.4.1, for arm64 and x64_64 targets. The solution works fine for arm64, but it fails for x86_64.

Specifically, I get this link error:

```
final section layout:
    __TEXT/__text addr=0x100003F70, size=0x0000001D, fileOffset=0x00003F70, type=1
    __TEXT/__stubs addr=0x100003F8E, size=0x00000006, fileOffset=0x00003F8E, type=29
    __TEXT/__stub_helper addr=0x100003F94, size=0x0000001A, fileOffset=0x00003F94, type=33
    __TEXT/__cstring addr=0x100003FAE, size=0x00000004, fileOffset=0x00003FAE, type=13
    __TEXT/__unwind_info addr=0x100003FB4, size=0x00000048, fileOffset=0x00003FB4, type=22
    __DATA_CONST/__got addr=0x100004000, size=0x00000008, fileOffset=0x00004000, type=30
    __DATA/__la_symbol_ptr addr=0x100008000, size=0x00000008, fileOffset=0x00008000, type=28
    __DATA/__data addr=0x100008040, size=0x025047A0, fileOffset=0x00008040, type=0
ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (-4256167970 max is +/-2GB): from _main (0x100003F70) to _kEmbeddedDataPack_sz (0x02504760) in '_main' from /Users/nickko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-fmueotrdocmveqccnonnadmvuhpd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TestApp.build/Debug/TestApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
```

For reference, this is the assembler file I'm generating:

```
.data
.balign 64
.global _kEmbeddedDataPack
_kEmbeddedDataPack:
.incbin "mydata.bin"
.global _kEmbeddedDataPack_end
_kEmbeddedDataPack_end:
.global _kEmbeddedDataPack_sz
.set _kEmbeddedDataPack_sz, . - _kEmbeddedDataPack
```

I've tried building with -fno-pic -fno-pie -no-pie, but it doesn't fix the problem. I've also tried to build with -mcmodel=large, but that causes a different linker error.

Is there a way I can get this solution to link successfully? I'd like to stick with the approach of generating an assembler file if possible, because I'm also targetting other platforms with clang (not just XCode / Mac).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _"Previously I was generating a C++ header file containing the data"_ - What if you only `extern` declare the array in the header file an define it in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: That wouldn't help because the problem is that the compiler is slow to compile the C++ array containing the data - whether it's in a header or source file.

Comment: In how many translation units is the header file included+

Comment: It's only included in one translation unit, that's not the issue.

Comment: Ok. Then unrelated, but I would suggest not having it in a header. Put it in a `.cpp` file so that you only need to recompile it if anything in it changes. Btw, how did you format your array and how long does it take for your compiler to compile it? What compiler is it?